# UserDetailsService is not invoked in spring security

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am trying to use spring security with two login page and configure two different http section in my spring-security.xml I also have two authentication-manager which handles authentication using custom UserDetailsService.

Below are my code snippets

**spring-security.xml**

```
 <!-- http Section for Admins -->
  <http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true" authentication-manager-ref="adminAuth" pattern="/admin/**">
    <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')" />


    <!-- access denied page -->
    <access-denied-handler error-page="/403" />

    <form-login login-page="/adminLogin" default-target-url="/admin/home" authentication-failure-url="/views/homePages/adminHome" username-parameter="username"
            password-parameter="password"
            login-processing-url="/authenticateAdmin" />
    <logout logout-success-url="/login?logout" />
    <!-- enable csrf protection -->
    <csrf disabled="true"/>
  </http>

  <authentication-manager id="adminAuth" alias="adminAuth">
    <authentication-provider user-service-ref='adminAuthService'>
      <password-encoder hash="md5" />
    </authentication-provider>
  </authentication-manager>

  <beans:bean id="adminAuthService" class="security.AdminAuth">
  </beans:bean>


  <!-- http Section for Students -->
  <http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true" authentication-manager-ref="studentAuth" pattern="/student/**" >
    <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_STUDENT')" />

    <!-- access denied page -->
    <access-denied-handler error-page="/403" />

    <form-login login-page="/studentLogin" default-target-url="/student/home" authentication-failure-url="/studentLogin" login-processing-url="/authenticateStudent" />
    <logout logout-success-url="/studentLogin"  />
    <!-- enable csrf protection -->
   <csrf disabled="true"/>
  </http>

  <authentication-manager id="studentAuth" alias="studentAuth">
    <authentication-provider user-service-ref='studentAuthService'>
      <password-encoder hash="md5" />
    </authentication-provider>
  </authentication-manager>

  <beans:bean id="studentAuthService" class="security.StudentAuth">
  </beans:bean>
```

**UserDetailService implementor class**

```
package security;

@Service
public class AdminAuth implements UserDetailsService {
    @Autowired
    AdminService adminService;
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String authAttribute) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        Admin admin = getAdminByUname(authAttribute);

        List<SimpleGrantedAuthority> authList = new ArrayList();
        authList.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_ADMIN"));

        User user =  new User(authAttribute, admin.getPassword(), authList);

        return user;
    }

    private Admin getAdminByUname(String authAttribute) {
        Admin admin = adminService.getAdminbyUname(authAttribute);
        return admin;
    }

}
```

**Admin login page**

```
 <h2 class="text-center">Staff Login</h2>
 <form class="login-form" action="/authenticateAdmin" method="POST">
  <div class="form-group">
   <label for="exampleInputEmail1" class="text-uppercase">Username</label> <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Email or Mobile" id="username">

  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
   <label for="exampleInputPassword1" class="text-uppercase">Password</label> <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="" id="password">
  </div>


  <div class="form-check">
   <label class="form-check-label"> <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input"> <small>Remember Me</small>
   </label>
   <button type="submit" class="btn btn-login float-right">Submit</button>
  </div>

 </form>
```

Now when I open login page enter username/password and hit login then my loadUserByUsername is not getting invoked.

What I doing wrong here.

Comment: action="authenticateAdmin" then resource  not found error

Comment: for action="admin/authenticateAdmin" it redirect back to login page with 403 access denied error in logs

Comment: So did you suggest to change form action to admin/authenticateAdmin?
But it throws access denied exception as user is anonymous

Comment: I know I did something wrong, But there is two cases
1. At time of login, I want to invoke userDetailsService class
2. Not allow to accessing admin pages to non-admin users

So I am not able to achieve both cases at a time
If I remove intercept-pattern then admin pages are open to all users

and I do not remove intercept-pattern then it login handler throws access denied

Comment: I have tried to add one more intercept-pattern to allow ***/authenticateAdmin*** like below

<intercept-url pattern="/authenticateAdmin" access="isAnonymous()"/>
 <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')" />

but still access denied

Comment: It is resolved by changing login processing url to admin/authenticateAdmin

I was confused about which url to change.


Thanks for the help